# Adding different formatters to Winston transports

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, formatting, winston

I need a different types of formatters for each transport.

Example:

```
logger = new (winston.Logger)({
    transports: [
        new (winston.transports.LogstashUDP)({
            // some config here. Do noting on formatting
        }),
        new (winston.transports.Mail)({
            // do formatting one way
        }),
        new (winston.transports.File)({
            // write to file as json (maybe format it here)
        }),
        new (winston.transports.Console)({
            // do another formatting
        })
    ]
});
```

As i can see from winston transports [docs](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/blob/master/docs/transports.md) only Console supports custom formatter.

I'm using `winston-mailer` module for mail and `winston-logstash-upd`

Is there any way to solve this with Winston? Or maybe how to create wrapper around one of these modules to support formatting?

Comment: I just have opened issue on their github: https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/issues/1567

Answer (score 3):

Here's the solution [posted to GitHub by dandv](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/issues/1401#issuecomment-403279367)

```
const logger = winston.createLogger({
  transports: [
    new winston.transports.File({
      filename: 'error.log', level: 'error',
      format: winston.format.simple(),
    }),
    new winston.transports.File({
      filename: 'combined.log', level: 'debug',
      format: winston.format.printf(info => `${new Date().toISOString(), ${info.message}`),
    }),
  ],
});

logger.error('prefixed by the timestamp only in `combined.log`');
```